# React with react-router-dom be pulled back to the page before after action complete

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I was using the react-router-dom and redux in my react application, and I had an issue.

When I emit an action from redux, and before the action done I change page immediately.

After the action was done, I was pulled back to the page before.

How could I solve this problem...?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Without code it is difficult to say why. It could be literally anything. Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example that reproduces the issue. If you can also get a working code sandbox up that would great.

Comment: The action triggered will definitely get terminated when you change the page. The component will load as soon as you change the page. Maybe you could have messed up in the page that you render. Please do add the code, so that it would be easy to sort out.

Comment: Thanks for your remind :)
I was finding my mistake,cause I push the history in actions after dispatch, so that it force the page be pulled back after dispatch...